# Group Policy processing and autologon on Windows 7

Tags: group-policy, login

I'm trying to accomplish a few things via Group Policy on Windows 7. Software Installation, map drives, map printer, etc.

I've got these computers set to autologon. The problem I'm running into is that the computers logon before DHCP has done its thing. Therefore, they don't apply any group policies properly.

How do I fix this? I've already set a policy to "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon". I've read up a bit and this doesn't actually mean that it waits for DHCP. So it's a little pointless.

Anything that would delay logon would work. Or if I can somehow make the computer wait for DHCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's another policy that needs to be configured on Windows Vista and higher:

> Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/System/Group Policy/Startup Policy Processing Wait Time

Set this to 120. Then run gpupdate /force /boot on the machines.